# How to persist .00 with float?

Tags: php, casting

I'm trying to convert a value from mysql to a float type.

I have a table with a decimal type column.

When I query the value from the table, the values are returned as string (expected in php).

When I convert a value with **floatval($value)**, it turns the value into float type in php.

The problem is that **floatval** drops .00 if I pass 33.00 as its parameter.

I do know that I can use number_format(), but that converts the value back to the string again.

How do I convert a string "33.00" into a float type in PHP?

Comment: Use floatval() to convert string to float; use sprint() or number_format() when displaying as output to show a set number of decimal places

Comment: If you're dealing with monetary values don't use `float` - you'll lose precision and the errors may propagate. Multiply by 100 and work in integers. Divide and format at the point of display.

Comment: @MarkBaker // The problem is 33 !== 33.00. If I use floatval("33.00"), it turns the value into 33, which isn't 33.00

Comment: You really need to understand loose typing in PHP: floatval("33.00") __does__ turn the value into a float (var_dump() will tell you that), but echoing a float will display ___significant___ digits (and 0s after the decimal point aren't significant). If yoy want to force the display of 2 decimal places, use sprint() or number_format()

Comment: @MarkBaker // I already do understand it. That's why I'm asking this question if there's any other workarounds.

Comment: If you want to compare floats, you also need to specify a precision, because digital computers cannot exactly represent a floating point value `if (abs(33 - 33.00) < 0.000000001) { echo 'equal'; } else { echo 'notequal'; }`

Comment: @MarkBaker // I guess there's no solution for this in PHP.. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Those aren't simply suggestions or workrounds, they are methods used by real developers in real world applications to deal with floating point values.... how the number is stored (as a float) and how it is displayed are something that you handle using number_format() or sprint() or equivalents in pretty much any programming language. 33 == 33.00 in mathematics; computers (using digital representation of floats) need to use the delta comparison that I've shown

Comment: @MarkBaker // I do understand your point, but my computer and my code is not a human being..and doing 33 === 33.00 simply returns false in php.

Comment: Doing `33 === 33.00` is __NOT__ comparing 2 floats, it's comparing an integer and a float, but a strongly typed comparison, so it will return false; doing `33 == 33.00` is a loose typed comparison and will return true

Comment: I think I have to explain my use case. So..a user saves a value (33.00) into a table. Later, the user tries to load the data and compares it with the value he/she entered. User enters 33.00 because he/she entered it before..in my code, there's just no way to compare them without doing extra things. Not a big problem..I can just drop the .00 and compare it..

Comment: Do it as a "loose" comparison , or convert both to float using floatval() and compare - but watch out for floating point precision issues http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score -1):

To quote W3C with my words (outputs) in the comments:

```
<?php
echo number_format("1000000")."<br>";//1,000,000
echo number_format("1000000",2)."<br>";//1,000,000.00
echo number_format("1000000",2,",",".");//1.000.000,00
?>
```

Simply change the 2 to any other number you want it to be.